# Script ending when calling function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a function that sets and then tests a variable within a powershell script.

The variable is set within the function but does not carry its value once back in the script. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it's something fairly simple that I'm missing.

This function is a part of a larger script.

I'm also not sure that my testing regarding a proper selection is working properly.

```
####Function to set and test Year level#####
function Year_Level
{
    do{
    $Selection=Read-Host "Choose a Year Level"
    Switch ($Selection)
    {
        0 {$YearLevel1="Year 00"}
                01 {$YearLevel1="Year 01"}
        02 {$YearLevel1="Year 02"}
        03 {$YearLevel1="Year 03"}
        04 {$YearLevel1="Year 04"}
        05 {$YearLevel1="Year 05"}
        06 {$YearLevel1="Year 06"}
        07 {$YearLevel1="Year 07"}
        08 {$YearLevel1="Year 08"}
        09 {$YearLevel1="Year 09"}
        10 {$YearLevel1="Year 10"}
        11 {$YearLevel1="Year 11"}
        12 {$YearLevel1="Year 12"}
        13 {$YearLevel1="Staff"}
        }

if($selection -ne 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13)
{Write-Warning "Incorrect year level selection, try again!" -Verbose
} else{
write-host "You have selected $YearLevel1"
}
    }until ($selection -lt 14)
}

Write-Host "Select Year Level"
Write-Host "0 = Reception"
Write-Host "01 = Year 1"
Write-Host "02 = Year 2"
Write-Host "03 = Year 3"
Write-Host "04 = Year 4"
Write-Host "05 = Year 5"
Write-Host "06 = Year 6"
Write-Host "07 = Year 7"
Write-Host "08 = Year 8"
Write-Host "09 = Year 9"
Write-Host "10 = Year 10"
Write-Host "11 = Year 11"
Write-Host "12 = Year 12"
Write-Host "13 = Staff"

Year_Level
```

I want to set the $yearlevel1 variable for use after the function in the script that calls the function.

EDIT

I have now got the variable set outside of the function. But sometimes it doesn't properly set/test what the variable is. Is there something glaringly obvious in the code that I'm missing?

```
function Year_Level
{
    do{
    $Selection=Read-Host "Choose a Year Level"
    Switch ($Selection)
    {
        0 {$YearLevel1="Year 00"}
        01 {$YearLevel1="Year 01"}
        02 {$YearLevel1="Year 02"}
        03 {$YearLevel1="Year 03"}
        04 {$YearLevel1="Year 04"}
        05 {$YearLevel1="Year 05"}
        06 {$YearLevel1="Year 06"}
        07 {$YearLevel1="Year 07"}
        08 {$YearLevel1="Year 08"}
        09 {$YearLevel1="Year 09"}
        10 {$YearLevel1="Year 10"}
        11 {$YearLevel1="Year 11"}
        12 {$YearLevel1="Year 12"}
        13 {$YearLevel1="Staff"}
        }

if($selection -gt 13)
{Write-Warning "Incorrect year level selection, try again!" -Verbose
} else{
write-host "You have selected $YearLevel1"
}
    }until ($selection -lt 14)
    $YearLevel1
}

Write-Host "Select Year Level"
Write-Host "0 = Reception"
Write-Host "01 = Year 1"
Write-Host "02 = Year 2"
Write-Host "03 = Year 3"
Write-Host "04 = Year 4"
Write-Host "05 = Year 5"
Write-Host "06 = Year 6"
Write-Host "07 = Year 7"
Write-Host "08 = Year 8"
Write-Host "09 = Year 9"
Write-Host "10 = Year 10"
Write-Host "11 = Year 11"
Write-Host "12 = Year 12"
Write-Host "13 = Staff"

$yearlevel = Year_Level
```

Answer (score 1):

`$yearlevel1` variable is defined and set inside function, hence it won't be available outside the function. I suggest to return the value from the function and store it in a variable.

```
function Year_Level {
    ....
    ....
    return $yearlevel1
}


$ReturnValue = year_level
```

But seems you are using the variable within the function rather than using it outside.
I would suggest you to try below approach for your requirement. Which is simple.

```
function Year_Level {
    $SupportedValues = 1..13
    do {
        $Selection = Read-Host "Choose a Year Level"
        if ($SupportedValues -notcontains $selection) {
            Write-Warning "Incorrect year level selection, try again!" -Verbose
        }
        else {
            $YearLevel1 = "Year $Selection"
            write-host "You have selected $YearLevel1"
        }

    }until ($selection -lt 14)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this solved the main issue I was having. it now seems that sometimes It does not properly return the correct year level. Since posting I have edited the code, I will post the new code.